# webpack tree shaking and split chunks together

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tree-shaking, webpack-splitchunks

We are using webpack `splitChunks` for bundling shared packages, now we did tree shake on our modules. 
(Our icons, ui components, hooks and helpers are npm package).

The problem is, our packages are fully tree shakable, but with `splitChunks` all of our packages considered as `vendor~main.js` and import without any tree shaking.

Do tree shaking only work for local imports?
How we should use both tree shaking and splitChunks for npm packages?